# Change version of ruby does not work on CentOS

Tags: centos, ruby

I'm trying to change version of the running ruby on a CentOs machine.

```
-# rvm use ruby-1.9.1-p378
-# ruby -v
-# ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i686-linux]
```

It is installed (by rvm) and I get no complains when I try to use that version, whereas I get complains when trying to use another version.

Anyone got any ideas on how to get this working? I'm essentially trying to install rails on top of this and I get a too-old-version complaint if I'm trying to install on 1.8.6.

Thanks for any input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably won't be an answer for this question since it magically worked when I logged on the next day...